# How do I set up a dev environment for c# on BodHi Linux (Ubuntu type system)

Tags: c#

I'm very confused about my move to Linux on my laptop. I want to set up a .netCORE dev enciroment and believe I have everything installed correctly, but none of the IDEs I have tried (Atom and VSCode) work as I expect from using VisualStudio.

For example in VisualStudio I go "create project" and a list of projects popup, like Console .NetCore or MonoGame or something.. I click on that and it starts. Atom and VScode seem to be just text editors. I can make a text file and save it to a directory or open a directory of text files.. there is no way to set as a console app for example. I am lituraly just typing text and then saving it.

In VS I hit F5 and it compiles and launches the console and runs the app... but Atom and VScode do not seem to have this. I mean vsCode has the F5 thing, but it dose not see to work. Even on near blank files.

How do I set up and IDE or use an IDE so I can code a simple console application on Linux in c#?

Answer (score 1):

Neither Atom nor Visual Studio Code is an IDE(Integrated Development Editor). They are simply text editors you can use to write down your source code. You will need to compile the source using an appropriate compiler.

You may use [Mono](https://www.monodevelop.com/) for this. It is an open-source implementation of the .NET framework so it runs smoothly in Linux. Install it by -

```
sudo apt install mono-complete
```

Now, write your program using Atom/Code and save it using a **.cs** extension. The next step is to compile your program using mono. Do this by -

```
mcs program.cs
```

Your program should compile correctly given it doesn't contain any error. Now you can run the resultant executable by -

```
mono program.exe
```

Additionally, install the Mono IDE if you want to use IDEs instead of the text editor+compiler combo. You can do this via -

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

Visit this [link for more information on mono downloads](https://www.monodevelop.com/download/). The [open-source project corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) is another viable alternative for mono.

Comment: sound great... unfortunatly those commands broke my system :( the install complete ran fine, but the install monodevelop didn't. I went to the official webpage and followed the instructions but the sudo tree hung the terminal, after ctrl+c to stop (like over an hour latter just in case) apt is now broken as the sources list is corrupted.